# Code Igniter - relative URLs stop working when URL ends in slash?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, href

I'm trying to learn CI and have just worked through the [starter tutorial](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html). I'm finding that some of the link HREFs don't work if my URL ends in a trailing slash - for example, these links:

```
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>

    <h2><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
    <div id="main">
        <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
    </div>
    <p><a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

The links to stories work fine when I'm on

```
/index.php/news
```

but not if I'm on

```
/index.php/news/
```

As I say, this is right from the tutorial, so I'm not sure what's up.

I can make the HREFs absolute....

```
<p><a href="<?php echo config_item('base_url').config_item('index_page').'/news/'.$news_item['slug']; ?>">View article</a></p>
```

...but figure I shouldn't have to.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why? This is not a general requirement of web development and CI's own tutorial doesn't do this.

Comment: CodeIgniter has the `site_url()` function which will fix your problem (it generates absolute urls). The problem is not a codeigniter issue, but rather how relative urls work in the first place. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

make it like this:

```
<a href="/news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a>
```

just adding the slash at the begining

**UPDATED:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

add this to your .htaccess file in the root of your application AND in the config file of codeigniter:

```
$config['index_page'] = ''; //make it like this
```

now you don't have to use the /index/news, just use the /news from the root of your site

so then you can use it like this:

```
<a href="/news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a>
```

it shut work

Comment: This is an option only if the site is in the server root.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this, but I'm curious why it's all necessary. Isn't CI support to handle stuff like this? This is from their own CI, so why there's stuff in it that doesn't work, I've no idea.

Comment: yeah this is the lack in their documentation

Comment: (edit: I meant of course "from their own *tutorial*", not "CI")

Comment: i found this post specially helpful, i used mod_rewrite and was not very pleased to see that site_url() and anchor() building urls that still has index.php the problem was solved by making $config['index_page'] = '';

Answer (score 2):

There might not be enough information here to diagnose the problem. "Doesn't work" -- What is the error?
What does the full URL look like?

It might be related to the your Apache and server configuration. Try editing the config and experimenting with "PATH_INFO" vs "REQUEST_URI".

```
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Lastly, (this is only slightly related) but the best way to build URLs in Codeigniter is the site_url() function (which creates a full URL):

```
echo site_url("news/local/123");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd have thought it was clear from my question what "doesn't work". As I said, when there is a trailing slash in the URL, the relative links in the page stop working. The tutorial has us create a news index page listing stories from the DB - /news. The links to the stories are /news/slug. CI renders the HREFs of these story links incorrectly if the news index page is viewed with a trailing slash.

Comment: Hi again. I think I was a little short with just saying your weren't clear enough. I think the things you should be looking at putting in your question to make it clearer are a) is it a 404 error b) is it displaying the wrong page c) some other error. Then something about the URL bar... the full URL eg. `http://localhost/index.php/news` vs `http://localhost/index.php/news/`. All these things affect your specific situation.

Answer (score 2):

Relative URLs won't work how you're expecting them to if you have urls in the following formats:

- http://domain.com/stuff/
- http://domain.com/stuff/things

The reason is because relative urls use the full URI path as a reference (hence "relative"). So, if you reference `stuff/things` (note preceding slash) while on the URI path of `/stuff/things` (note no end slash), you will get `/stuff/stuff/things` because it assumes you want something in the `stuff` folder.

What I would do is use CodeIgniter's `site_url()` function because it will generate absolute urls (including domain) for you.

`site_url('stuff/things')` will become `http://domain.com/stuff/things`

For this case specifically, use `echo site_url('news/'.$news_item['slug']);` within your anchor's href. You can also do `echo anchor('news/'.$news_item['slug'], 'Link text to this article');` to echo a link to the article without writing the html.

One caveat-- `site_url()` will include `index.php` in the URI (if it has not been removed from your config file), so if you want to reference images, javascript, css, etc, then use `base_url()` which will only reference your `base_path` config variable.

Edit: forgot to mention, you will need to use the [URL Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) for these functions to work.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still puzzled how I managed to run into this from their own tutorial, though - I haven't changed a thing. You'd have thought the tutorial would work out of the box. Re: removing the index file, I'm not sure what you mean here. Another answerer mentioned this; do I just set an empty value for `index_page` in the config? Doing this seems to break the whole site.

Comment: Do I have to load some library for `site_url()` to work? The function doesn't appear to be defined (confirmed with `function_exists()`) *EDIT* - seems it should be `$this->config->site_url()`

Comment: You need the URL Helper loaded. `$this->load->helper('url')` or add it to your autoload.php in the application/config folder under the helpers array. Removing the index.php from `index_page` will only work if you have url rewriting in place in apache or nginx (or whatever your webserver is).

Answer (score 1):

maybe it is too late, but i have suffered from this problem, despite doing all the suggestion, the problem still!
now it works finally, just put

```
$config['base_url'] = '/myrootfolder/';
```

instead of

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myrootfolder/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your config.php then remove the index.php .

Then after that use

```
echo base_url('news').'/'.$news_item['slug']
```

Then configure your route like

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/index/$1';
```

Comment: By 'remove' I guess you mean set the config item as an empty string rather than remove it completely. I did this, and used the `base_url()` function, but now a) the news items no longer appear on the news index; b) going to the site root throws a page-not-found (not a 404 generated by CI)